# C# The node must be of type 'JsonArray'

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I am trying to add an empty Json object "d" in JsonNode as array, manually adds "c" without error, but in loop compiler throws an exception *The node must be of type 'JsonArray'*

```
string jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize("{\"a\":\"55\",\"b\":\"66\"}");

var jsonNode = JsonNode.Parse(jsonData);
        
JsonNode jsonNodeEmpty = JsonNode.Parse("{}");
jsonNode["c"] = jsonNodeEmpty; // adding manually no error
foreach (var item in jsonNode.AsArray())
{
    jsonNode["d"] = jsonNodeEmpty; // throws an exception  The node must be of type 'JsonArray'
}
```

I tried also `new JsonArray(jsonNodeEmpty);` instead of `jsonNodeEmpty` in loop but still same error: *Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The node must be of type 'JsonArray'*

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to serialise a string?! deserialising the result of serialising a string will result in a, dun dun dun, a string. `jsonNode` is a string and therefore  I would expect the error to come from `jsonNode.AsArray()`

Comment: Are you sure the exception does not come from the `AsArray` call? What stack trace do you get?

Comment: That's right, it comes from AsArray
```at System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonNode.AsArray()```
but, is there any other way to loop without it?

Comment: @Nodo what do you want to reach?  Can you show a json you are trying to create?

Comment: @Serge I am trying to add new object in JsonNode.  The result shoul be something like that ```{"a":"55","b":"66", "c":[]}```
In realworld it is huge json object and I want to add some elements in loop.

Comment: Why would you want to repeat `jsonNode["d"] = jsonNodeEmpty;` for each `item` in `jsonNode.AsArray()`? I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Anyway,

`"{\"a\":\"55\",\"b\":\"66\"}"` is not a string that represents a JSON array and C# is not Javascript.

Comment: @Jodrell I just wanted to add an element in json in loop.

```{"a":"55","b":"66"}``` is source Json, trying to add new element in loop for example c and d to get like this ```{"a":"55","b":"66","c":"77","d":"88"}```

Comment: What you have in the string is a `JsonObject`. So you want to be calling this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonobject.add?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-nodes-jsonobject-add(system-string-system-text-json-nodes-jsonnode)

Answer (score 2):

You JsonNode is not array, if you need look JObject elements try this:

```
var jsonNode = JsonNode.Parse("{\"a\":\"55\",\"b\":\"66\"}");

JsonNode jsonNodeEmpty = JsonNode.Parse("{}");
jsonNode["c"] = jsonNodeEmpty; // adding manually no error

foreach (var item in jsonNode.AsObject())
{
   var i=item;
   var jsonNodeEmptyNew = JsonNode.Parse("{}");
  // jsonNode["d"] = jsonNodeEmptyNew; you don't modify collection in foreach
}
```

Comment: You are right, that was not an array.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
string jsonData = "{\"a\":\"55\",\"b\":\"66\"}";

    var items = JsonNode.Parse(jsonData);

    items["c0"] = JsonNode.Parse("[]");

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        items["c" + i.ToString()] = JsonNode.Parse("[]");
    }
```

result

```
{
  "a": "55",
  "b": "66",
  "c0": [],
  "c1": [],
  "c2": [],
  "c3": [],
  "c4": [],
  "c5": [],
  "c6": [],
  "c7": [],
  "c8": [],
  "c9": []
}
```

Comment: That's Great! 

Answer (score 0):

My actual mistake was that I was looping and changing using `foreach`, Thanks to @Serge. If you loop through `for` change or add new element like in PHP is not a problem.

```
        string jsonData = "[{\"a\":\"11\",\"b\":\"22\"}, {\"a\":\"111\",\"b\":\"222\"}]";
        var items = JsonNode.Parse(jsonData);
        Console.WriteLine(items.ToJsonString());
        for (int i = 0; i < items.AsArray().Count; i++){
            items[i]["a"] = 1111;
            items[i]["zz"] = "added from loop";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(items.ToJsonString());
```

Result of this code:

```
[{"a":"11","b":"22"},{"a":"111","b":"222"}]
[{"a":1111,"b":"22","zz":"added from loop"},{"a":1111,"b":"222","zz":"added from loop"}]
```